# Mysql empty fields

Tags: mysql

I have a soccer registration site. Sometimes an empty field gets registered (I think one of the users presses the registration button twice, because a successful and an empty registration always happen at the same time). This happens rarely, not every time.

My code is this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO events (event_name, registrant_name, date_registration) VALUES ('$event_number', '$username', NOW())";
```

`$event_number` and `NOW()` get registered every time. `$username` is sometimes empty. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to show the relevant code. Your SQL-statement is ok.

Comment: Add constraints to your database for example.

Comment: Check that the username field has a value before you allow the insert? Make username not null?

Comment: Validate your inputs properly before applying them to the database. I suspect your code is susceptible to SQL Injection too.

Comment: @ Hobo Sapiens: This is a private site so I am not worried about sql injections.

Comment: @10now You will be when Mr O'Sullivan (or O'Dowd, O'Brien, etc) wants to register. The single quote will break your query.

Comment: or mister `Smith;DROP ALL TABLES` registers   ... mwuuuuhahahahaha !!!!

Comment: "one of the users presses the registration button twice" - but surely the form action takes you to a new page where you process the input  (an check its validity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `NOT NULL` constrain to user_name field:

```
ALTER TABLE events MODIFY username varchar(255) NOT NULL;
```

or check in you PHP code, is user_name is empty?

```
if(!empty($username)) {
  $sql="INSERT INTO events (event_name, registrant_name, date_registration) VALUES ('$event_number', '$username', NOW())";
  //run query
} else {
 //handle error as you want
}
```

Comment: seems like the best answer so far. I will try it now. Thanks Manwal.

Comment: Why downvote?  @FedericoRazzoli OP don't want to inster `NULL` in any case. So i have given PHP solution like you `strlen($username) > 0` same as `!empty($username)`.

Comment: Setting it to NULL is correct, I agree. But I'm afraid it won't solve your problem, because the query you shown cannot insert a NULL value.

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli i know query can't insert null value. That error can be easily `mysqli_error()` or PHP functions.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should probably add a UNIQUE index. Unless you do it, you can have double usernames.

Your PHP code should check that `strlen($username) > 0`. Alternatively, you can do this check in an SQL trigger, but in your case there is probably no reason to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disagree with the answers which suggest declaring the column as `UNIQUE` or `NOT NULL`. Well, it doesn't hurt, I Suppose, but they are not the answer to your seemingly badly designed code (which you have not posted).

A database solution seems to me to be a last line of defence, which would not be necessary if there were a first line of define - properly validating and sanitizing user input before passing it to the database.

Using PDO makes this easier.

From my comments above:

- "one of the users presses the registration button twice" - but surely the form action takes you to a new page where you process the input (and check its validity)?
- what if someone registers as mister `Smith;DROP ALL TABLES`? Neither `UNIQUE` nor `NOT NULL` will save you then

Comment: You don't disagree my answer :) since I didn't say that the use of a UNIQUE index solves the problem. However, it fixes a worse problem (exactly like your suggestion about SQL injection)

Comment: Ok, we agree (+1 :-) Just so long as the OP and anyone who look sat this question in future learns how to make their data safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the problem with this trick:

```
INSERT INTO events (event_name, registrant_name, date_registration)  
SELECT '$event_number', '$username', NOW()
FROM DUAL
WHERE length($username) > 0
```

Comment: Instead of FROM (SELECT 1), you can use FROM DUAL :)

Comment: As a side note, in most cases you can omit the FROM clause at all. FROM DUAL is necessary for non-trivial SELECTs (like the one you posted, probably)

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli yes - to use a where, you need a from. I've changed it to use dual too - good idea.